# Merging 2 csv files inorder

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to prepare a data set(labels) for my deep Neural network.[image]

The above Image shows the data which struggling to prepare.
I want to merge image column with their respective level in a perfect manner.
As we can the Data is splitted
I would like to both in one single manner for eg

```html
Image Column     level column
1_left            0
1_right           0
...
...
10_left           0
10_right          0
...
15_left           2  
15_right          2  
...
```

The excel sheet can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=151IyX9O2gyAtvgFE4ivxDDg7nRZUxcMA)
pandas merge and join is not able to result it the way I would like to have it.
Please guide me
Yours Sincerely,
Vidit Shah

Comment: Please provide input data as text and not an image.

Comment: @ScottBoston,I have added the download link for the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Downloads/all.xlsx')
df1 = df.rename(columns={'image':'image.0','level':'level.0'}).reset_index()
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df1, ['image','level'], 'index','value','.','.')
```

Ouput:

```
                image  level
index value                 
0     0       10_left    0.0
1     0      10_right    0.0
2     0       13_left    0.0
3     0      13_right    0.0
4     0       15_left    1.0
.
.
.
53571 1      44346_right    0.0
53572 1       44350_left    0.0
53573 1      44350_right    0.0
53574 1       44351_left    0.0
53575 1      44351_right    0.0
```